# Variable not passing into function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

I tried to google this but couldn't find a solution. So the problem is I'm trying to execute something once if user window width is changed to specific width+-, however; the variable is **undefined** inside the function for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var n = 1;

if(windowWidth >= 900) { 
    var tc = 3; 
    $(".debug").html(tc); // Making sure if user window width is 900 or more and tc is 3 on page load.
} else if (windowWidth <= 900) {
    var tc = 2;
    $(".debug").html(tc); // Making sure if user window width is 900 or less and tc is 2 on page load.
}

function liveWidthChange(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $(".debug2").html("<b>current width:</b> " + windowWidth + " - <b>tc:</b> " + tc); 
    if (tc == 3 && windowWidth <= 900) {
         // Shows how many times executed if activly changing browser width and the current value of tc
        $(".debug").html("tc Value: " + tc);
        var tc = 2;
    }
}

// If the browser changes size
var RS = false;
$(window).resize(function() { 
    if (RS !== false) clearTimeout(RS);
    RS = setTimeout(liveWidthChange, 200);
});    

});
```

So if user has window width of 900 or more, it sets `tc` variable to 3, if user is resizing browser and it goes under 900, execute something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), also [this article](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/01/19/the-cost-of-privacy/) could be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `tc` in a place where all the functions will have access to it:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var n = 1;
var tc; // here, at the top.
```

Then you just need to remove the `var` in each location you set the value of `tc`.

Answer (score 1):

I see several things.

You always redeclare the variable `tc`, instead you should move it on top

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  var originalWidth = $(window).width();
  var n = 1;
  var tc = 2;
  var MAX_WIDTH = 900;
  [...]
```

You will be confused by naming two different variable with the same name:

In the ready block:

```
var originalWidth = $(window).width();
```

In the function:

```
var currentWidth = $(window).width();
```

You are using the operator `'=='` in order to compare integers, you should use `'==='` instead unless you know what you are doing.

```
x = "5"
>>> x == 5
true
>>> x === 5
false
```

In your condition you have

```
if(windowWidth >= 900) {}  else if (windowWidth <= 900) {}
```

What if the windowWidth = 900, it will always go inside the first condition...

I beleive that you may want to use `'<'` or `'>'`